# How to find distinct dictionary keys?

Tags: swift, dictionary

I have a dictionary like this:

```
var dictionary: [String: String] = ["one": "Value 1", "two": "value2", "two": "value3", "one": "value4"]
```

How can I find distinct keys from the dictionary in Swift 3.0 ???

Comment: Swift dictionary cannot have duplicated keys. Only one of those will be kept.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH8-ID113: *"... Each value is associated with a **unique** key,  ..."*

Comment: @kennytm "Swift dictionary cannot **has** ..." sorry 

Answer (score 1):

Main goal of the dictionary is to have always only one key. Or in other words, that keys are always unique.

This brings very quick search inside dictionary with (at best) O(1) to search a value for key.

If dictionaries would allow more than one copy of the key, this quick search would not be possible. It would be also confusing, because if you ask dictionary a value for key "A", witch one it would return?

Thats why in all languages, dictionary ensure that there is always only one key.

If you set value for same key, it will override previous value, and not insert new one with same key.

---

**Addition**

If you put your code in playground it will fire an error

```
fatal error: Dictionary literal contains duplicate keys
```